# What's the proper way to make a menu for an ASP.net application?

Tags: asp.net

Making a left hand side menu for my website.

Should I create a Unordered List and add them as list-item?

What way is the proper way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the usual way to make a menu.  Often the menu will be contained in a DIV with headers being the menu section header and the unordered list elements comprising the menu items.  Use CSS to style the list (say to remove the bullets and add a background) so that it looks the way you want your menu to appear.  You may want to consider one of many JS frameworks/plugins to add some interactivity to your menu.  One I've used is [jQuery](http://jquery.com) + [fgmenu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/) from the Filament Group (though the example below is not in the correct format for it).

```
<div id="nav">
   <h3>Main</h3>
   <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
   </ul>
   <h3>Other</h3>
   <ul>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```